# Transporting content from one webpage to another in the same website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, rss

Quick, easy question that I know you guys will be able to solve quite easily.

I havent been able to find a solution possibly due to the way I have been wording my searches.

Basically, I have a testimonials page containing multiple client feedback and I would like to copy this information to the index page displaying 2 of the most recent pieces of feedback. This information basically contains H2, H3 and simple p structure.

I would guess that using some sort of javascript or an iframe or probably something even a lot simpler than this will be the answer. If I could convert this information into an RSS feed this would be even better then this would save me some CSS hassle later (will make sense after you have read the next paragraph).

If possible I would like to reformat the 2 front page entries to match another feed I have generated from an RSS feed using CSS but I can manage this part myself.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Just a little heads up I have never used AJAX and not the best with jQuery.

Your help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Where is the testimonial data stored?

Comment: in the testimonials.html page... flat html type text structure. in an article within a div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery ajax (specifically `$().load`) to request your testimonials page from the index page, then scrape the content you'd like and append it to the index page. Something like this:

```
$('#targetElementOnIndexPage').load(
    urlToTestimonialPage + ' #sourceElementOnTestimonialPage');
```

See the documentation for [$().load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more examples.

> If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Comment: thanks I will give this a shot and how do you embed this into your html code? for example JS would use <script></script>?.

Comment: The best practice is to put javascript in it's own javascript file, and then include it by putting a `<script>` tag in the header of the html page.